# You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have wrapped my **index.js** file to support a **Redux Store** and **React-Router-v4**.

However, when I try to run a basic test, I get the following error message:

```
Invariant Violation: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>
```

Here is what my **index.js** looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from "./store/index";

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

and here is my **App.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScaleLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Main from './Main';
import './styles/styles.scss';

// Redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import store from "./store/index";
import { isLoading } from "./actions/index";

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        store.dispatch(isLoading(true));
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
            store.dispatch(isLoading(true));
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='App'>
                <Header />
                <div className='App__wrapper'>
                    <div className={'loading-spinner ' + (this.props.isLoading ? null : '--hide-loader')}>
                        <ScaleLoader
                            color={'#123abc'}
                            loading={this.props.isLoading}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <Main />
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ isLoading: state.isLoading });

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));
```

Since I'm using **withRouter** to wrap for navigation, is this method discouraged? Should I be setting up **withRouter** at the **index.js** level?

Thank you!

Comment: what if you wrap `App` like `<span> <App /> </span>`. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing your BrowserRouter like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Then replace everywhere it appears BrowserRouter with Router instead.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Just an FYI: the application works fine. It's the Unit Test that fails.

Comment: Missunderstood the question sorry. Are you using Jest for testing purposes?

Comment: Yes. I decided to use create-react-app to spawn and eject this time around, and it comes with Jest.